# Matlab - Replace every second column with another vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have Matrix A with n,n dimensions.
How can I replace every second column of A with column vector x (of size n).

I want to do it without any "for/while" loops,

can someone please help me? 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%// Create example data
n = 21
A = magic(n)
x = ones(size(A,1),1);
%// Replace every second column of A with x starting from the first column
m = ceil(size(A, 2)/2);
X = x(:, ones(1,m)); %//Replicate x
A(:,1:2:end) = X %// Put x in each odd column.
```

If you want it to start from the second column then you must use `floor` instead of `ceil`

```
%//Create example data
n = 6
A = magic(n)
x = ones(n,1);
%// Replace every second column of A with x starting from the second column
m = floor(size(A, 2)/2);
X = x(:, ones(1,m));
A(:,2:2:end) = X
```

Comment: the first 3 lines are for creating from X a matrix (n,n)?

Comment: @Rami yes. You only need the last three lines. The first three are just creating example data

Comment: why do I need the x vector to be a matrix? why can't it stay a simple vector?

Comment: @Rami Matlab won't allow you to assign a vector to a matrix. You can assign a scalar to every element of a matrix but not a vector. Matrix assignment needs to be 1 to 1, so you you need to change `x` to a matrix `X` that has columns equal to the number of columns you are assigning to (and the same rows obviously)

Answer (score 4):

Suppose this is your data:

```
A = rand(11);
V = ones(size(A,1),1);
```

Then this is how you assign the vector to each second column of the matrix:

```
idx = 2:2:size(A,2)
A(:,idx) = repmat(V,numel(idx))
```